# Why this error occure E/chromium: [ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(249)] Cannot start http server for devtools. Stop devtools

Tags: android

My android studio version 3.0.1.

```
   E/chromium: [ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(249)] Cannot start http server for devtools. Stop devtools.
```