# Cannot start http server for devtools. Stop devtools / HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

On startup I am getting the following error message shown in logcat.

`org.chromium.chrome E/chromium: [ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(249)] Cannot start http server for devtools. Stop devtools.`

I am running Chromium build 65.0.3317.0.  This error does not happen on a previous version of Chromium, 54.0.2840.9, and the chromium devtools works fine.  When I try to inspect a remote android device using devtools a blank tab opens with the error `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.

I'll also attach the different in the files that are throwing the error.

Chromium 54 - devtools_http_handler.cc

```
void StartServerOnHandlerThread(
    base::WeakPtr<DevToolsHttpHandler> handler,
    base::Thread* thread,
    DevToolsHttpHandler::ServerSocketFactory* server_socket_factory,
    const base::FilePath& output_directory,
    const base::FilePath& frontend_dir,
    bool bundles_resources) {
  DCHECK(thread->task_runner()->BelongsToCurrentThread());
  ServerWrapper* server_wrapper = nullptr;
  std::unique_ptr<net::ServerSocket> server_socket =
      server_socket_factory->CreateForHttpServer();
  std::unique_ptr<net::IPEndPoint> ip_address(new net::IPEndPoint);
  if (server_socket) {
    server_wrapper = new ServerWrapper(handler, std::move(server_socket),
                                       frontend_dir, bundles_resources);
    if (!output_directory.empty())
      server_wrapper->WriteActivePortToUserProfile(output_directory);

    if (server_wrapper->GetLocalAddress(ip_address.get()) != net::OK)
      ip_address.reset();
  } else {
    ip_address.reset();
    LOG(ERROR) << "Cannot start http server for devtools. Stop devtools.";
  }
  BrowserThread::PostTask(BrowserThread::UI, FROM_HERE,
      base::Bind(&ServerStartedOnUI,
                 handler,
                 thread,
                 server_wrapper,
                 server_socket_factory,
                 base::Passed(&ip_address)));
}
```

Chromim 65 - devtools_http_handler.cc

```
void StartServerOnHandlerThread(
    base::WeakPtr<DevToolsHttpHandler> handler,
    std::unique_ptr<base::Thread> thread,
    std::unique_ptr<DevToolsSocketFactory> socket_factory,
    const base::FilePath& output_directory,
    const base::FilePath& frontend_dir,
    const std::string& browser_guid,
    bool bundles_resources) {
  DCHECK(thread->task_runner()->BelongsToCurrentThread());
  std::unique_ptr<ServerWrapper> server_wrapper;
  std::unique_ptr<net::ServerSocket> server_socket =
      socket_factory->CreateForHttpServer();
  std::unique_ptr<net::IPEndPoint> ip_address(new net::IPEndPoint);
  if (server_socket) {
    server_wrapper.reset(new ServerWrapper(handler, std::move(server_socket),
                                           frontend_dir, bundles_resources));
    if (server_wrapper->GetLocalAddress(ip_address.get()) != net::OK)
      ip_address.reset();
  } else {
    ip_address.reset();
  }

  if (ip_address) {
    std::string message = base::StringPrintf(
        "\nDevTools listening on ws://%s%s\n", ip_address->ToString().c_str(),
        browser_guid.c_str());
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", message.c_str());
    fflush(stderr);

    // Write this port to a well-known file in the profile directory
    // so Telemetry can pick it up.
    if (!output_directory.empty()) {
      base::FilePath path =
          output_directory.Append(kDevToolsActivePortFileName);
      std::string port_target_string = base::StringPrintf(
          "%d\n%s", ip_address->port(), browser_guid.c_str());
      if (base::WriteFile(path, port_target_string.c_str(),
                          static_cast<int>(port_target_string.length())) < 0) {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Error writing DevTools active port to file";
      }
    }
  } else {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Cannot start http server for devtools. Stop devtools.";
  }

  BrowserThread::PostTask(
      BrowserThread::UI, FROM_HERE,
      base::BindOnce(&ServerStartedOnUI, std::move(handler), thread.release(),
                     server_wrapper.release(), socket_factory.release(),
                     std::move(ip_address)));
}
```

You will notice that the 65 version is doing a boolean check on the ip_address value where as 54 only checks the server_socket.

I realize there is an unanswered post [Cannot start http devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884292/why-this-error-occure-e-chromium-errordevtools-http-handler-cc249-cannot-s) but that is 3 months old with no response.